# Проблемы с заголовками ответа node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Всем привет. Запускаю простенький сервер на node.js, содержащий 1 статичный html файл из которого посылаю запрос к стороннему серверу и получаю в ответ ошибку

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8888' is therefore not allowed access

т.к. отсутствует соотвествующий заголовок, что странно, т.к. в коде я прописал все как нужно.

Код, который я запускаю:

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'localhost');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
next();
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'content')));


app.get("/target", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+ '/content/index.html');
});

app.listen(8888);
console.log("Server is listen on 8888 port")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: `ajax` не может в кроссдоменные запросы, на какой адрес отправляете запрос?

Comment: @ThisMan https://target.my.com/api/v2/oauth2/token.json

Comment: И почему XMLHttpRequest  не умеет к кроссдоменные запросы?  Судя по документации - при правильно реалзации CORS такие запросы работают - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XDomainRequest.

Answer (score 1):

У вас проблема с хостом,который указан в заголовке:

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'localhost');
```

Вот тут должно быть так:

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

Это если вы хотите чтобы все запросы из инета проходили.Если не хотите - просто напишите некоторый список адресов.

Comment: Забыл поменять в посте, что это уже сделано. И что странно: запрос проходит и мне корректный ответ приходит, но в консоль та же ошибка выводится.

Comment: Вы можете добавить маленький модуль body-parser и убрать вообще все установки заголовков. Насколько я помню,проблема должна уйти.