# Два сервера на Node.js No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: node.js, nginx

Добрый день.

У меня фронт на React запускается через Node.js на localhost:3000 и сам сервер (api) на Node.js localhost:4000.

На фронте я пытаюсь сделать запрос:

```
fetch('http://localhost:4000/', {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Content-type":
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        }
    })
```

Вы падает ошибка:

Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:4000. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что мне делать? Nginx настравивать?

Comment: Фронт через шторм запускаете?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблемы с заголовками ответа node.js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/470524/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-node-js)

Comment: Нет. В консоли скрипт запускаю, прописанный в package. Скрипт запускает ноду на express

Comment: @Darth довольно "остроумно" отмечать решенный вопрос дубликатом нерешенного, особенно когда у них разные проблемы...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Node которая на 4000 порту (которая api) надо указать пачку заголовков для ajax запросов.

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",  "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "DELETE, PUT, UPDATE, HEAD, OPTIONS, GET, POST");
```

Comment: Где указать?
Для ответа?

Comment: Ну да. Можно поставить в начале middleware, которое будет снабжать данными заголовками любой ответ на любой запрос

Comment: `app.use((res, res, next) => { ... код из моего ответа ... ; next(); });`

Comment: Nginx в теории тоже может отрезать эти заголовки, так что попробуйте его убрать и постучать напрямую в ноду, чтобы убедится что дело в нём (или не в нём))

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` - лишний

Comment: Тут надо перечислять только заголовки, добавляемые вручную, а не все подряд. Кроме того, простые заголовки (Accept, Accept-Language, Content-Language, Content-Type) разрешены всегда.